# How to solve $\int e^{7t/240}\sin t\,dt$?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I use integral by part twice, but still unable to solve the integral problem. Can anyone help?
[image][image]

Here is my own calculation, it is just like a loop for $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrqpi.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrqpi.jpg)

Comment: Integration by parts twice should get you to something of the form $I=f+aI$ where $I$ is your integral, $f$ is some explicit function of $t$ and $a$ is a number. Then you can solve this equation for the unknown $I$.

Comment: So I do not have to solve the whole integral, but instead, I can get a function direcrtly for the whole integration?

Comment: I don't know exactly what that means, but once you have that equation with the desired integral on both sides, it's just like any equation with an unknown in it, and you can solve it for the unknown just by algebra.

Comment: But my left-hand side does not have any integral

Comment: I attached my calculation steps

Comment: At the top of the second page of your notes, you have an "equation" with nothing on the left side of the equals sign. What's supposed to be there? Isn't it supposed to be the integral you are asking about?

Comment: I do not know why I can not attach my following steps,  But it that like  = f+a  , then -a=f ,   =f/(1-a) ?

Comment: Yes, cynthia, exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

*Shorter than integration by parts.*

$$\int e^{\frac{7t}{240}} \sin (t)\,dt =\Im \Big[\int e^{\frac{7t}{240}} e^{it}\,dt\Big]=\Im \Big[\int e^{\left(\frac{7}{240}+i\right) t}\,dt\Big]$$
$$\int e^{\left(\frac{7}{240}+i\right) t}\,dt=\left(\frac{1680}{57649}-\frac{57600 i}{57649}\right)
   e^{\left(\frac{7}{240}+i\right) t}$$
$$\Im \Big[\int e^{\left(\frac{7}{240}+i\right) t}\,dt\Big]=-\frac{240  (240 \cos (t)-7 \sin (t))}{57649}e^{\frac{7t}{240}}$$

Comment: Very nice, though I wouldn't bet that OP knows from complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use integration by parts to get the result $$I=\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)dx$$
$$I=\sin(bx)\int e^{ax}dx-\int\left(b\cos(bx)\frac1ae^{ax}\right)dx$$
$$I=\frac1ae^{ax}\sin(bx)-\frac ba\int e^{ax} \cos(bx)dx$$
$$I=\frac1ae^{ax}\sin(bx)-\frac ba\left(\cos(bx)\int e^{ax}dx-\int (-b\sin(bx))\frac1ae^{ax}dx\right)$$
$$I=\frac1ae^{ax}\sin(bx)-\frac ba\left(\frac1ae^{ax}\cos(bx)+\frac ba\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)dx\right)$$
$$I=\frac1ae^{ax}\sin(bx)-\frac ba\left(\frac1ae^{ax}\cos(bx)+\frac baI\right)$$
$$I=\frac1ae^{ax}\sin(bx)-\frac{b}{a^2}e^{ax}\cos(bx)-\frac{b^2}{a^2}I$$
$$I\left(1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)=\frac{ae^{ax}\sin(bx)-be^{ax}cos(bx)}{a^2}$$
$$\frac{(a^2+b^2)I}{a^2}=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2}\left(a\sin (bx)-b\cos(bx)\right)$$
$$\boxed{I=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\sin (bx)-b\cos(bx)\right)}$$

Comment: I think I might just going to remember it lol

Comment: You can derive it easily if you don't want to remember. I just gave you the formula. Do you want derivation?

Comment: Yes,please, thank you so much

Comment: Now, you can check it